# jQuery - Class does not really change on click (it changes only once)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm coding a simple html page with some jQuery. I have two links and I want to change the style of them when one is clicked. In particular, I want to make the clicked one with a border and the unclicked one without.

```
$('.unclicked').click(function (event) {
    $('.clicked').removeClass('clicked').addClass('unclicked');
    $(this).removeClass('unclicked').addClass('clicked');
});

<a href="1.html" class="clicked">1</a>
<a href="2.html" class="unclicked">2</a>
```

Thanks for your suggestions

This code works only once, meaning that when I click on the newly unclicked element does not change its class.

Comment: Have you tried adding the click handler to the newly unclicked object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/live/

You want to use

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '.unclicked', function() {
//your code here
});
```

This is because you are destroying the item that the function is attached to, but not telling it to add it to the new item.

Answer (score 1):

Use delegation for live events...

```
$(document).on('click', '.unclicked', function (event) {
  //....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a neutral class to all links you want this behavior attached to. Like:

```
<a href="1.html" class="clickable">1</a>
<a href="2.html" class="clickable">2</a>
```

Then use the `toggleClass` function.

```
$('.clickable')
// Before any are clicked, set the class to unclicked
.addClass('unclicked')
.on('click', function () {
    // This automatically removes and adds based on what's already present.
    $(this).toggleClass('unclicked clicked');
});
```